# Dynamic in Mathematica without duplication of code

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to create three separate graphs, this code will give you the idea:

```
f[t_] := Sin[10 t] + Cos[15 t];
Slider[Dynamic[dx], {0.01, 1}]
var = Dynamic[Fourier[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100, dx}]]];
ListLinePlot[Abs[var]]
ListLinePlot[Re[var]]
ListLinePlot[Im[var]]
```

This won't work because var hasn't been evaluated an so ListLinePlot/Abs/Re/Im does not recognize it as a list of numbers. Dynamic has to wrap ListLinePlot.

Wrapping ListLinePlot and everything else with Dynamic works. But then I would have to calculate Fourier[Table[... once for each graph. Per principle, I don't want to have this duplication of code.

This is a way that avoids duplication of code but is not as semantic as my proposed not working example above, plus it puts all series in one graph and not in three separate:

```
Dynamic[
 ListLinePlot[
  (#[Fourier[
       Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100, dx}]
       ]]) & /@ {Abs,Re,Min}, DataRange -> {0, 100}
  ]
 ]
```

Hopefully you can see now what I am trying to achieve. Something like my first piece of code except it should work. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you seen the new [Mathematica StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)?  Most people who used to answer in the \[mathematica\] tag have moved there.  You might get better replies faster there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you only need to wrap `Dynamic` around the expression that needs to be recomputed.  As you noticed, if you wrap `Dynamic` around the contents of `var`, it will not work because `ListPlot` will see a `Dynamic` head, not the list, when you pass `var` to it.  What needs to be recomputed in this case is the complete `ListPlot`.

The correct solution is to use  a delayed definition for `var` (i.e. `:=` instead of `=`) and wrap `Dynamic` around `ListPlot`:

```
f[t_] := Sin[10 t] + Cos[15 t];
Slider[Dynamic[dx], {0.01, 1}]

var := Fourier[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100, dx}]];

Dynamic@ListLinePlot[Abs[var]]
Dynamic@ListLinePlot[Re[var]]
Dynamic@ListLinePlot[Im[var]]
```

People often get confused with `Dynamic` because it sometimes shows up deep within in expression, e.g. in your `Slider` example.  But there `Dynamic` has a different function: setting a value.

Generally, unless used to set a value, `Dynamic` always needs to be the outermost head in an expression.  (There are some exceptions, notably when we're handling expressions that *directly* correspond to what is shown on screen, and are handled by the front end, such as graphics primitives:  `Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 5}]`, `Graphics[{Disk[], Dynamic@Disk[{x, 0}]}]` will work.)

`Dynamic` affects only the way expressions are displayed in the front end, not how the kernel sees them.  Here's an example:

```
x=1
arr = {Dynamic[x], 2, 3}
```

The Front End will display `arr` as `{1, 2, 3}`, but the kernel still sees it as `{Dynamic[x], 2, 3}`.  So if we calculate `Total[arr]`, the front end will display it as `1 + 5` but the kernel will see if as `Dynamic[x] + 5`.  I hope this clarifies the situation a bit.

*Note:* I did not want to use `Manipulate` in this solution because the OP didn't use it either.  `Manipulate` is just a high level convenience function and everything it does can be achieved with `Dynamic` and some controls such as `Slider`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
f[t_] := Sin[10 t] + Cos[15 t]

DynamicModule[{var},
 Manipulate[
  var = Fourier[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100, dx}]];
  {ListLinePlot[Abs[var]],
   ListLinePlot[Re[var]],
   ListLinePlot[Im[var]]},
  {dx, 0.01, 1}
]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
f[t_] := Sin[10 t] + Cos[15 t];
Slider[Dynamic[dx], {0.01, 1}]
Dynamic[var = Fourier[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100, dx}]]];
Dynamic[ListLinePlot[Abs[var]]]
Dynamic[ListLinePlot[Re[var]]]
Dynamic[ListLinePlot[Im[var]]]
```

I think this should calculate `Fourier` just once. From my understanding, the `ListLinePlot`s should be triggered by the change of var after evaluating `Fourier` (note that the assignment of `var` is *inside* the `Dynamic`).

Comment: I can't get this to work. It looks like it has the same problem.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I currently cannot test it. But did you make sure that all the old definitions are cleared out (preferrably by starting a fresh kernel)? And how do you check how often Fourier is executed? Note that moving a slider may trigger execution for several *different* values. What happens if you assign to `dx` directly?

Comment: I know that the list is right because what happens is it prints it out on red background. Like this: ListLinePlot[Abs[<list of Fourier-transformed numbers (complex as opposed to f[t])>]]. The values change as turn the slider.